# OpenLayers map add combo in panel

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, style, html, jquery

I just want to add combo box on OpenLayers map panel. I don't know how to add combo to the OpenLayers panel so currently I have set absolute location to combobox, like this http://jsfiddle.net/4zNH6/

```
<div id="map">
    <select id="combo">
    <option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
    <option value="pune">Pune</option>
    <option value="bangalore">Bangalore</option>
  </select>
</div>

#combo{
    position:absolute; 
    left:10px; 
    top:10px; 
    z-index:10000; 
    width:100px; 
    height:20px; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**Is this a right approach to place element on map??=** or is it possible to add element in panel(OpenLayers.Control.Panel)?? and then add panel in map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to use GeoExt with Openlayers, check this out:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ACrcn/1/

Code:

```
var data = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
    fields: ["STATE_NAME", "STATE_ABBR"],
    proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
            callbackKey: "format_options",
            callbackPrefix: "callback:",
            url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
            params: {
                service: "WFS",
                version: "1.1.0",
                request: "GetFeature",
                typeName: "topp:states",
                srsName: "EPSG:3857",
                outputFormat: "json"
            }
        })
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: data,
    displayField: "STATE_NAME",
    valueField: "feature",
    emptyText: "Select a state",
    mode: "local",
    triggerAction: "all",
    renderTo: document.body
});
new Ext.Button({
    text: "Show on map",
    handler: function() {
        result.removeAllFeatures();
        result.addFeatures([combo.getValue()]);
        result.map.zoomToExtent(result.getDataExtent());
    },
    renderTo: document.body
});
var result = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
new GeoExt.MapPanel({
    layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(), result],
    center: [0,0],
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
    renderTo: document.body
});
```

See more at:

- http://geoext.org/examples.html
- http://presentations.opengeo.org/2012_javascript/javascript/concepts.html

Comment: Thanks, Its great help. I will try to impliment Geoext. But I may be unable to explain my question sorry for this. Actully I want to add combo overlay on map like this http://jsfiddle.net/4zNH6/. In example i have set absolute position but is it possible to do same thing using openlayer control??

Comment: @Amit you're welcome! but I don't understand, your jsfiddle example shows how to do it, so it works as you want, doesn't it?

Comment: @Amit just to add I don't think there is a "combo" control in OL, something like "OpenLayers.Control.Combo" class if that's what you mean. Here you have the controls: `http://docs.openlayers.org/library/controls.html`

Comment: Ohh.. If there is no OpenLayers.Control.Combo then the only way to add combo on map is by applying style , _am i right_?? If you have some usefull links regarding  overlay html element on map it will great help. **Thanks a lot Gery** .

Comment: @Amit you're welcome! yeah you're right, you'd need to play with html and Javascript/CSS to style in the way you want. I think GeoExt can be a better solution, check the examples, and with GeoExt you will connect things easily between the client (OpenLayers), the server-side (GeoServer or MapServer) and the backend (PostGis/PostgreSQL) of your application.